# Constructor of superclass is entered without me wanting it to

Tags: java

I have a class `PageRankMonteCarlo` that extends `PageRankSparse`. `PageRankMonteCarlo` has a constructor which is called in `main()`. Inside of the constructor, `PageRankSparse.readDocs()` is called, to set up some variables of the `PageRankMonteCarlo` object.

When I run `PageRankMonteCarlo`, the constructor of `PageRankSparse` is executed, even though I don't want it to. This leads to `readDocs` being called twice, since `readDocs` is also called in `PageRankSparse()`. Here's the code:

PageRankMonteCarlo.java:

```
package pagerank;

public class PageRankMonteCarlo extends PageRankSparse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Please provide a filename");
        }
        new PageRankMonteCarlo(args[0]);
    }

    public PageRankMonteCarlo(String filename) {
        NUMBER_OF_DOCS = readDocs(filename);
        System.out.printf("NUMBER_OF_DOCS: %d\n", NUMBER_OF_DOCS);

    }
}
```

PageRankSparse.java:

```
public class PageRankSparse {


    public PageRankSparse( String filename ) {
    int noOfDocs = readDocs( filename );
    NUMBER_OF_DOCS = noOfDocs;
    iterate( noOfDocs, 1000 );
    }

    // For testing
    public PageRankSparse() {
            int noOfDocs = readDocs("links5.txt");
            NUMBER_OF_DOCS = noOfDocs;
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------- */


    /**
     *   Reads the documents and fills the data structures. 
     *
     *   @return the number of documents read.
     */
    int readDocs( String filename ) {
        int fileIndex = 0;
        System.out.println("reading...");
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    if ( args.length != 1 ) {
        System.err.println( "Please give the name of the link file" );
    }
    else {
        new PageRankSparse( args[0] );
    }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
reading...
reading...
NUMBER_OF_DOCS: 0
```

As you can see, `readDocs` has been executed twice. This leads to unintended behaviour.

How can I make sure `readDocs` is only executed one time? I've tried this (removing `readDocs()` call from subclass constructor):

```
public class PageRankMonteCarlo extends PageRankSparse {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Please provide a filename");
        }
        new PageRankMonteCarlo(args[0]);
    }

    public PageRankMonteCarlo(String filename) {
        System.out.printf("NUMBER_OF_DOCS: %d\n", NUMBER_OF_DOCS);
    }
}
```

But there are two problems:

1. It feels weird to pass `String filename` to subclass constructor when it doesn't even use it.
2. The wrong superclass constructor is called. I want `PageRankMonteCarlo(String filename)` to be executed. Instead, `PageRankMonteCarlo()` is executed.

How can I get the behaviour I want?

Comment: Yea, superclass constructors are called first. That's why you shouldn't put stuff in constructors carelessly. How about removing everything from both constructors and using a separate load method to load the data.

Comment: But I need to `readDocs` in the constructor of the superclass, because the superclass can be run on its own as well. If I don't run it there, I need to run it in main() of the superclass, and then I have to make everything static...

Comment: No you don't. You can call the constructor and then call a method. You don't need to have your constructors call methods. As you see it can cause problems, so it's best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the filename to the superclass constructor. If it's something the superclass also needs to do, it should be handled in the superclass.

```
public PageRankMonteCarlo(String filename) {
    super(filename);
    System.out.printf("NUMBER_OF_DOCS: %d\n", NUMBER_OF_DOCS);
}
```

If you need to avoid doing something that the superclass constructor does (like the `iterate` call), you could make it conditional with another parameter:

```
public PageRankSparse( String filename, boolean doIterate ) {
    int noOfDocs = readDocs( filename );
    NUMBER_OF_DOCS = noOfDocs;
    if (doIterate) {
        iterate( noOfDocs, 1000 );
    }
}
```

and have the subclass call `super(filename, false);`.

Also, I would recommend removing that "for testing" no-arg constructor, which is what the subclass constructor is calling now (all constructors will automatically call `super()` unless a super call is specified). You can test the class by calling the normal constructor with `"links5.txt"`.